# How to access DSLR camera memory card?

Tags: java, opencv, camera, javacv

I want to a access Camera memory that connected via usb in to computer using java libraries. I tried third party libraries like jusb etc.

Jfile chooser also not recognized camera memory because, windows identify camera as portable device.

I want to access memory card of a DSLR , Sony or any other digital camera  using java....

Javacv(open cv) approach also ok.. Pls help.....

Comment: Unless you camera is designed to support USB drive, the only option is to ask the vendor how you might do it and they are likely to reply that you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your camera can be mounted as an USB drive, you won't be able to directly access the memory card's file system.

In order to communicate with your camera, you'll need to use the [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) or [PTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) protocol.

There are some libraries out there that may help you achieve this, such as [JPhoto](http://jphoto.sourceforge.net/) or [cameraptp](http://code.google.com/p/cameraptp/).